# formatação de string

Tags: python, texto

Possuo a seguinte string:

```
JOSÉ CARLOS ALMEIDA         (0-2) 1
```

preciso retirar o texto e os espaços e deixar `(0-2) 1`

desas maneira consigo tratar com o `trim`, split etc...

porem essa minha string nao vai ser sempre igual as vezes pode vir:

```
JOSÉ SAMUEL         (0-2) 1
```

e ou

```
CARLOS MANGUEIRA        (0-2) 1
```

como posso tratar essas variações?

Comment: sempre virá (0-2) 1 no final? ou pode variar tipo (10-25) 1

Comment: Daniel, pode variar sim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monte uma substring com o índice inicial na abertura dos parênteses e que vai até o final.

```
str = 'CARLOS MANGUEIRA        (0-2) 1'  # string de exemplo
index = str.find('(')  # indice comecando na abertura de parenteses
substr = str[index:]  # substring que vai do indice até o fim da string de exemplo
print substr
```

Resultado:

> (0-2) 1

Funciona independente da quantidade de dígitos dentro dos parênteses.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer também com expressões regulares, considerando que o padrão seja sempre o mesmo:

```
(número-número) número
```

Onde `número` seria qualquer sequência de dígitos (i.e. números inteiros não negativos), a regex ficaria:

```
\(\d+\-\d+\)\s\d+
```

Extraindo o conteúdo das strings:

```
import re

values = [
  "JOSÉ CARLOS ALMEIDA         (0-2) 1",
  "JOSÉ SAMUEL         (3-4) 7",
  "CARLOS MANGUEIRA        (2-10) 99"
]

for value in values:
  result = re.search(r"\(\d+\-\d+\)\s\d+", value)
  if result:
    print(result.group(0))
```

A saída é:

```
(0-2) 1
(3-4) 7
(2-10) 99
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/GTLH/0).